I built my docker image and when I tried to login into my ecr repository on my jenkins pipeline is outputs an error
[Pipeline] sh

aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1
docker login --username AWS --password-stdin accountID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
I have input my aws access keys and secret keys to jenkins UI and my instance yet it tells there are no credentials
I have manually logged in the repository to my instance and that works but doesn't when I run my pipeline
